# Loop points in polygon based on subset of two columns in R

Tags: r, polygon, point, loop

I have a spatial point data frame with two columns with attributes, one for months, another for species (and off-course the lat, long for those points).

```
long=c(-1.747429,-1.519554,0.430455,-2.049941,-1.288655,1.311327,-2.217094,0.718583,-1.646491)

lat= c(54.407632,53.369744,51.519982,52.347591,54.530768,51.12631,53.430349,51.552895,55.028696)

species = c('d','c','d','d','d','c','c','c','c')

month = c(1,2,3,2,3,4,3,2,3)
```

I also have a spatial polygon of my country projected in the same CRS as my points.

I want to create a loop that will give me the count of points per month and species and that output to be in separate data frames.

But so far I only know how to do count points in polygon overall

```
Df2<-over(Df, poly)

df2Freq<-count(Df2, "NAME_1")
```

What I want is a loop that will do by month and species and produce multiple data frames with outputs

Answer (score 1):

I will provide you a reproducible example. First, I'll create a point object and a polygon. The point object has `month` and `species` field:

```
library(sp)
library(raster)

point <- new("SpatialPointsDataFrame"
             , data = structure(list(month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), species = c(1, 
                                                                                          2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2)), .Names = c("month", "species"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                     -10L), class = "data.frame")
             , coords.nrs = numeric(0)
             , coords = structure(c(-71.2611979005976, -71.2613792984669, -71.262302778529, 
                                    -71.2594333940505, -71.2594828661966, -71.2629624071448, -71.263556072899, 
                                    -71.2606866884204, -71.2589881447348, -71.258658330427, -29.9447590462946, 
                                    -29.9441159083943, -29.9436541683632, -29.9428131418781, -29.9417577360929, 
                                    -29.945484637772, -29.9446271205715, -29.9421040411162, -29.941972115393, 
                                    -29.9423019297009), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
                                                                                            c("coords.x1", "coords.x2")))
             , bbox = structure(c(-71.263556072899, -29.945484637772, -71.258658330427, 
                                  -29.9417577360929), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("coords.x1", 
                                                                                           "coords.x2"), c("min", "max")))
             , proj4string = new("CRS"
                                 , projargs = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"
             )
)

e <- extent(point@bbox)
e <- as(e,"SpatialPolygons")
e@proj4string <- point@proj4string

plot(e)
plot(point,add=T,col='red')
```

[image]

To extract what you want, use a loop selecting points by month. I created a list called `plist` to store each `data.frame` and also the month is added to each `data.frame`.

```
plist <- list()

for(i in unique(point$month)){
  p <- point[point$month == i,]
  index <- as.numeric(names(over(p,e)))
  plist[[i]] <- data.frame(as.data.frame(table(point$species[index])),month=i)
}
```

Check the resulting `list` with `data.frame`s:

```
plist

## [[1]]
##   Var1 Freq month
## 1    1    2     1
## 2    2    1     1
## 3    3    1     1
## 
## [[2]]
##   Var1 Freq month
## 1    2    1     2
## 2    3    2     2
## 
## [[3]]
##   Var1 Freq month
## 1    1    1     3
## 2    2    1     3
## 3    3    1     3
```

`Var1` is specie ID and `Freq` is count by specie.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on `dlply()` from **plyr** embedded in a `group_by`-and-`summarise` pipeline from **dplyr**. Although I generally prefer to rely on fewer external packages in my code, I must admit that these two packages perform amazingly fast when it comes to such kinds of operations. I assume that your species data set has already been clipped, thus making an explicit call to `over` (or eg `raster::crop`) obsolete.

```
## sample data
library(sp)

dat = data.frame(long, lat, month, species)
coordinates(dat) = ~ long + lat # optionally set spatial context for future use
proj4string(dat) = "+init=epsg:4326"

## group into data.frames with species counts per month
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

dat@data %>%
  group_by(month, species) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  dlply("month")

# $`1`
# month species count
#     1       d     1
# 
# $`2`
# month species count
#     2       c     2
#     2       d     1
# 
# $`3`
# month species count
#     3       c     2
#     3       d     2
# 
# $`4`
# month species count
#     4       c     1
```